# How to make your own mailing services like gmail or yahoo

Tags: php, email, localhost, database-mail

I am a noob to php and databases. But I have an idea to perform mail operations on my own web server (i.e just by database operations), but I really don't have any idea of how to send mail to external websites like gmail. and also I look forward to making my own email-addresses like ex:-myownemail@localhost. I have searched google multiple times but I couldn't find any answer that I could understand. Can anyone tell me in simple words on how to do this?

Comment: There's really no point in doing this. Ever since spam email became a serious problem around the world, most major companies are using something called [The Spamhaus Block list](https://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/). If your server isn't considdered an official mailserver, Hotmail, Yahoo etc will completely block any email coming from you. They won't even end up in the spam boxes.

Comment: Im doing this just as an hobby project so i dont really care if it goes to spam ..i just wanna succeed in this project,but i really have no idea where to start..a reference would be great for me!..ty in advance

Comment: Aside from that, this question can be considdered "Too Broad" according to SO guidelines. This means it would require writing half a book to answer your question correctly. Please have a look at our [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and specifically at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Anyway, here's a good tutorial on how to do this on Linux: http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/ . On Windows it's simply a matter of downloading a program. These can very easily be found by Googling `How to set up a mail server Windows / Linux`. I have no idea how you were unable to find anything yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to have a webhost, grab a free one for testing purposes which supports mail function. Then after you are done setting up your host, try the following.

To send a mail, since you don't care if it goes to spam, use this simple php code:

```
<?php
$to = "xyz@somedomain.com";
$subject = "This is subject";

$message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
$message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

$header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
$header = "Cc:afgh@somedomain.com \r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

if( $retval == true )
{
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
}
else
{
    echo "Message could not be sent...";
}
?>
```

If you just want to read mails using PHP, PHP has [native functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imap.php) to talk to IMAP, NNTP and POP mailboxes.

Comment: The PHP mail function isn't going to help him at all if he's using his own server (as said in the question) and he didn't setup a mailserver at all. PHP can't magicly just mail.

Comment: Sorry I don't want to be the ass here, really :) But the question is how to setup mail on localhost on his own server. He wants to learn how to setup and use his own mailserver. Not how to use an external one :P Hence the "Too Broad". That's not something you can explain in a short answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a `mail server` and a program for accessing mail,which works on  [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) (Internet Message Access Protocol).

For Mail server and `IMAP` server we have lot open source projects.

I Found this great tutorial which is used [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) and [dovecot](https://www.dovecot.org/).

http://aurellem.org/free/html/email.html